# Active Model Serializer issue for Nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

`ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.project, include: [collaborator: :pictures]).as_json[:project]`

When object.project is nil  then it occurs an issue.
NoMethodError:  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to ActiveModelSerializers (AMS) after all. In Ruby, `nil` causes a lot of `NoMethodError`, so we often avoid `nil`s with `if` or `unless` modifiers.
For example, in your case, we often do 
`ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.project, include: [collaborator: :pictures]).as_json[:project] if object.project`